# Cfwindow destroys page

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfwindow

I have an issue with cfwindow. I have a search page and each result gets it's own cfwindow. Well when I open any of these cfwindows it takes the background image I have and puts it on top of the content (even if modal is set to true or false) and then after you close the window it will stay that way. No way to get back to the pages content without using the back button, and that just brings you back to the page where you did the search first.

Here is the output for each search result aswell as where it creates the cfwindow.

```
    <cfoutput query="mysearch">
     <cfobject name="development" component="TATN.development" type="component">
        <cfset pageName = development.getListingName("#mysearch.key#")>
    <!--- build our cfWindow --->
 <cfwindow x="40" y="40" closable="true" draggable="false" initShow="false" modal="true" name="#pageName#" refreshOnShow = "true" resizable="true" height="800" width="825" source="/hotels/#pageName#.cfm"
        title="#mysearch.custom3#" />
   <div id="hotels_results" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='##FFBCBC';" onMouseOut="style.backgroundColor='##FFEDED';">
        <div class="thumbimg">        
         <a href="javascript:ColdFusion.Window.show('#pageName#')"><img src="/photos/slideshowPhotos/#mysearch.key#/one.jpg" border="0" width="180" height="115" alt="Click to View More Information."> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="hotels_text">
         If I were asked under what sky the human mind has most fully developed some of its choicest gifts, has most deeply pondered on the greatest problems of life, Welcome text goes here.<br>
            <div class="hotels_book_now"> 
             <a href="##" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Book Now','','images/h_book_now1.jpg',1)">
                <img src="images/h_book_now.jpg" alt="Book Now" name="Book Now" width="113" height="38" border="0" align="top"></a>
            </div>
         <h3>Starting at $1000 a night</h3>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="hotels_ratings">
                <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star">
                <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star">
                <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star">
                <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star">
                <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>



 </cfoutput>
```

Comment: Can you link to a sample page that shows the problem?  Hard to quite understand what's going on from your description.

Comment: Is the background image from the parent page of the cfwindows? Does it work as expected if you omit the background image to test?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I believe you're missing the value attribute in the hotels_ratings radio inputs.

Comment: What is the value of #pageName#?

Comment: I just re-created your scenario and it seems to work fine for me. It would be appreciated if you could give more of the source code.

Comment: Indeed, not only would it help clarify the question here, the best way to debug this situation on your own is to reduce the problem to its simplest possible form in which it still occurs. It sounds like you need to make a simple page with a background image and one or two cfwindows. If that page still has this issue, post its source.